# Why can't my list items style be none it doesn't affect it at all

Tags: html, css

I want my list items to have no style types but `list-style-type` doesn't affect anything. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  *grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; /*
  /*grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); */
  grid-template-columns:repeat(1, 1fr);
  background: #8B8E93;
 grid-gap:1em;
}

.grid > div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: white;
  grid-gap:1em;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(odd){
  background: #8B8E93;
  grid-gap:1em;
}

.box1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-gap:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <img class="logo" src="Test.jpg" width="267px" height="150px" alt="logo" class="logo">
 </div>
  
  <div class="box1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="navmenu">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Computer Repair.html" class="navmenu"> Computer Repairs</a></li>
      <li><a href="Shop.html" class="navmenu">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="About us.html" class="navmenu">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact us.html" class="navmenu">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="FAQ.html" class="navmenu">FAQ</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Full code](https://hastebin.com/acuqoyucuz.xml).

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on asking questions. SO is not a free coding service, questions typically require more effort than "here is a dump of my code, what's wrong with it?". Try narrowing down your code example to only the information someone would need to address the problem, as well as describing exactly what you've tried so far and what didn't work. The better-structured your question, the better answers you'll get.

Comment: Well I don't see why its not working correctly. People could see what I mean, I posted everything just because I need to know if any of my code is interfering with each other

Comment: Please add your code to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your list items to have no markers at all?

First of all, you should apply such properties to `<ul>` not to parent `<div>`.

If you want only to hide markers, you should use `list-style: none;`. If you want to do something else, use `list-style-type` with desired value.

```
.box1 > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't. It doesn't change anything

Comment: @MichaelCallahan, I'd like to know what exactly you're expecting.

Comment: When i open the html file the markers are still there although I used list style the way you said and the way i know. And the markers are still there

Comment: I got it now... I hate css